# Locking in MySQL

Tags: mysql, locking

I have recently started a fairly large web project which is going to use MySQL as a database. I am not completely familiar with MySQL, but I know enough to make simple queries and generally do all that I need to.

I was told that I needed to lock my tables before writing to them? Is this necessary every time? Surely MySQL would have some sort of built in feature to handle concurrent reading and writing of the database?

In short, when should I use locking, and how should I go about doing so?

Comment: Why don't you just explain your issues? "I was told that I needed to lock my tables before writing to them" --- without any particular question this phrase is incorrect.

Comment: Locks are automatic using standard sql. If your table needs to be locked MySQL will do it for you.

Comment: @zerkms A colleague of mine just told me to make sure I locked my tables before writing to them. I wasn't exactly sure why or if this was necessary, which is why I am asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an excellent explanation of when and how to implement locking:  http://www.brainbell.com/tutors/php/php_mysql/When_and_how_to_lock_tables.html

As per El yobo's suggestion:

If you are doing one off select querys, there is not going to be a problem.
From the article:

> Locking is required only when
>   developing scripts that first read a
>   value from a database and later write
>   that value to the database.

Comment: Good link, but I think you should also summarise it by saying "you probably don't need to worry about it" :)

Comment: Thanks, this is was I was looking for. So I only need to explicitly lock tables when I am doing a transaction, not for single queries?

Comment: @DanieL: if you need a `transaction`, then perform a `transaction`. There is nothing to do with locks then.

Comment: Not even that much; if you're using transactions, any locking will automatically be handled for you.  Just remember that the MyISAM engine doesn't support transactions, so you will need to use explicit locks instead of transactions if you want to use MyISAM; in general, use InnoDB, not MyISAM.

Comment: @El Yobo: there is no reason to "want" to use myisam if you need in transactions ;-)

Comment: @zerkms - as far as I can tell there is no reason to *ever* want to use MyISAM, unless you really don't like your data and want to punish it ;)  My response was intended to be to DanieL's comment, not to yours (posted at the same time, I think).

Comment: Thanks heaps guys, I'm pretty sure I understand it now, I'd just never heard of transactions before today so I was a bit confused. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

In short, dont use myisam use innodb instead. When you want to insert, update or delete (CRUD) rows do:

```
start transaction;

insert into users (username) values ('f00');
...

commit; -- or rollback
```

when you want to fetch rows just select them:

```
select user_id, username from users;
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: +1 InnoDB.  As a long time Postgres user, the existence of engines that *don't* support the basic functions of a database (e.g. MyISAM failing to support transactions, foreign keys and check constraints) was something of a shock when I first used MySQL.

Comment: You should also point out that the transactions are only required if you want to do *more* than one statement and need to ensure that they either all fail or all succeed, or to ensure that the data is consistent for the duration of the transaction.